# What does invoking call method inside another constructor function do?

Tags: javascript, constructor, this

I have two constructor functions here: Car and Van

```
    var Car = function (location) {
        this.loc = location
    };

    Car.prototype.move = function () {
        this.loc++
    }

    var Van = function (location) {
      Car.call(this, location)
    }
```

Could you tell me what this line `Car.call(this, location)` is doing? My assumption is that we want to inherit the loc property from the Car class to the Van class.

My confusion is on what now **this** inside

```
    Car.call(this, location)
```

is referring to? and also what **this** inside Car

```
    var Car = function (location) {
        this.loc = location
    };
```

is referring to? Can someone provide any insight?

Comment: No you will have to Link the `Van`  constructor to `Car`

Comment: Can you elaborate further? What do you mean?

Comment: `Car.prototype = Object.create(Van.prototype)` this will link the `Van prototype` to the `Car's prototype`  now the question where `this` is refer to, `Car.call(this, location)` in this case it will refer to the `Van`

Comment: When called with `new` the `Van` constructor's `this` refers to the newly created `Van` instance. This line `Car.call(this, location)` calls the `Car` constructor but the context is explicitly set to the `Van` instance so `this.loc` inside `Car` now actually refers to the `Van` instance. If you would just call `Car(location)` then `this` within `Car` would point to the global object (window) instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
Car.call(this, location)
```

this will associate the `.loc` property to the Van object. `this` here refers to the `Van`.
If you instantiate `Van`, it will associate the same

```
var v = new Van(1); // v.loc=1
```